# DataGridView scroll bars greyed out when called from a thread

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a windows form app written in C#. I took all the code that, (does a restapi call,builds a list,  puts the list into a datagridview) into a thread so I can check the thread and update the customer as it is running. When doing this everything works except the scroll bars are greyed out.

Comment: Without code, you can't get much help.  You should only interact with GUI controls on the main thread.  Use other threads to do the work on data, and then pass it to the GUI control.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a problem with scrollbars only?
If your code still in main thread, your form isn't able to do anything.(you need double check)

But it is true, you can use `Application.DoEvents();` after finish bind data to gridView.
This method will stop all thread and update view, please make sure this is not a perfect solution, this method will bring irreversible error sometimes when cross thread condition.

Anyway, I hope to use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` to make it simple.
Here is sample.
After starting form, timer will work 100 times and interval is 5 seconds.

```cs
private int loopCnt = 1;

// you don't need to this, just drag timer component from a "tool box"
// to your form any where at design time(mode).
// private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(); 

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //it is up to you start timer at form-load or triggering after some button click.
    //this.loopCnt = 1; 

    this.timer1.Enabled = true;
    this.timer1.Interval = 1000 * 5;
    this.timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateDataAndBind(loopCnt++);
    if(loopCnt > 100)
    {
        this.timer1.Stop();
    }
}

public void CreateDataAndBind(int loopCount)
{
    DataSet dsTemp = new DataSet();

    #region : Define data Table and columns

    DataTable dtTemp = new DataTable();
    DataColumn dColKey = new DataColumn("key", typeof(int));
    DataColumn dColName = new DataColumn("name", typeof(String));

    dtTemp.Columns.Add(dColKey);
    dtTemp.Columns.Add(dColName);

    dtTemp.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("role"));
    dtTemp.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("timeText", typeof(String)));
    dtTemp.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("timeValue", typeof(DateTime)));

    #endregion


    dsTemp.Tables.Add(dtTemp);

    for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++)
    {
        DataRow dRow = dtTemp.NewRow();
        dRow[0] = loopCount;
        dRow[1] = "jornathan";
        dRow[2] = "Developer";
        dRow[3] = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        dRow[4] = DateTime.Now;
        dtTemp.Rows.Add(dRow);
    }

    this.BindDataSet(dsTemp);

}

public delegate void updateDataSetDelegate(DataSet ds);

private void BindDataSet(DataSet ds)
{
    if (this.dataGridView1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new updateDataSetDelegate(BindDataSet), new object[] { ds });
    }
    else
    {
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    }

}
```